# How to install Jest on macOS Mojave

Tags: node.js, macos-mojave

On a MacBook Pro (Mojave) I have installed Node (it works).

```
npm install --save-dev jest
```

runs without errors, BUT jest is still not available:

```
jest --version bash: jest: command not found
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Just because the command is not found does not mean it is not installed. You may have to navigate to the location, add the location to your default path, or use a fully qualified path to the executable you intend to run.

Comment: De-installing Node and re-installing everything "globally" (option -g) has solved the problem. Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: I'm so happy you were able to resolve the problem on your own. Please post the fix as an answer to your own question and then hit the green check mark to accept your answer and close this question. You get points and people will stop coming here trying to help you.